# High Number of TIME_WAIT Connections in Redis Cluster mode

Tags: redis

we have encountered with the Redis cluster recently, and we are seeking your expertise to help us understand and resolve it.

Upon bringing up the Redis cluster on three machines with one replica, we observed an immediate surge in the number of connections, as evidenced by the 25,000 connections in the TIME_WAIT state when checking netstat. This has raised concerns as it seems unusual for the cluster and its replica to establish such a large number of connections.

We are aware of potential ways to mitigate this issue, such as adjusting the system's TIME_WAIT duration and implementing connection reuse. However, we want to better understand the root cause before applying any changes.

We kindly request your assistance in identifying the reasons behind the Redis machines opening a significant number of connections and potentially leading to the TIME_WAIT state. If you could provide insights into the factors contributing to this behavior and suggest appropriate solutions, it would greatly help us in addressing this issue effectively.

If you require any additional logs or configuration files to analyze the situation, please let us know, and we will promptly provide the requested information.

WE bring up a single machine without cluster and we don't see the problem